# Can't acces Sort property in a telerik:RadComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, telerik

I have a Telerik ComboBox :

```
<telerik:RadComboBox  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True" SelectedIndex="0" x:Name="CbBoxUltra" SelectionChanged="CbBoxUltra_SelectionChanged" MinWidth="100"/>
```

I'm doing a "for each" loop to store items into it :

```
foreach (var ultra in line2)
{
...
    if (deviceType != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(vehicleName) && vehicleName != "null" && deviceType == "ultra")
    {
        _listUltra.Add(new UltraModel { Id = Convert.ToInt32(idUltra), Name = nameUltra, NameVehicle = vehicleName });
        CbBoxUltra.Items.Add(vehicleName);
    }
}
```

I want to sort the items in my ComboBox (from a to z for exemple).
So I tried to do what's in the doc : [Telerik's sorting](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/combobox/functionality/sorting)

But in the .xaml, i can't acces the property "Sort", like I do with "VerticalAlignment" for example, and i can't access the property in the .xaml.cs neither :

```
CbBoxUltra.Items.Sort(); //It doesn't match anything here
```

I just can acces .SortDescription, but it's not what I'm searching for...

Comment: How about `CbBoxUltra.Sort();`?

Comment: Same thing, it doesn't match anything

Comment: From the docs, it's a property used like this `CbBoxUltra.Sort = RadComboBoxSort.Descending;`

Comment: With your code, i have :"The name 'RadComboBoxSort' does not exist in the current context";

Comment: http://www.telerik.com/forums/362691-radcombobox-sorting

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I gathered from Telerik's documentation, the `Sort` property is available only for [ASP.NET RadComboBox Control](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/api/server/Telerik.Web.UI/RadComboBox#properties-Sort) (server-side), and not for [WPF RadComboBox Control](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/api/html/T_Telerik_Windows_Controls_RadComboBox.htm).

That given, there are two most common ways to proceed.

**I. Take advantage of the existing WPF implementation**

`RadComboBox.Items` property is actually inherited from `ItemsControl`. It is of type `ItemCollection`, which implements `ICollectionView`, and supports sorting via `SortDescriptions` collection. So if you want to sort by property values, you can simply add appropriate items to that collection:

```
CbBoxUltra.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription
{
    PropertyName = "XXX",
    Direction = ListSortDirection.Descending
});
CbBoxUltra.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription
{
    PropertyName = "YYY",
    Direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending
});
```

This code will cause the items to be sorted first by the `XXX` property in descending order, then by `YYY` property in ascending order. However if your sorting logic requires more than just referencing item property values, you can add a single sort description, leaving out the `PropertyName`:

```
CbBoxUltra.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription
{
    Direction = ListSortDirection.Descending
});
```

This will cause the sorting mechanism to sort using the default comparer for your item type. In order to apply custom logic, make sure your items implement [IComparable<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd(v=vs.110).aspx) interface. Ddefault comparer for `string` sorts in lexical order.

**II. Pre-sort items before adding**

This approach is somewhat easier provided you add items only once. Here's code excerpt:

```
foreach (var ultra in line2.OrderByDescending(...))
{
    ...
}
```

Note that in case you'll be adding items multiple times (e.g. upon user input), this will get much trickier since you'll have to manually insert items at proper indexes.